# Combination of list of list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I want a list which is a combination of list of list elements
For example: 
my input

```
x = [['P'], ['E', 'C'], ['E', 'P', 'C']]
```

The output should be

```
['PEE','PEP','PEC','PCE','PCP','PCC']]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Should the last one not be PCC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
[''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(*x)]
```

Note: assuming that last one should be 'PCC'

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution

```
def comb(character_list_list):
  res = ['']
  for character_list in character_list_list:
    res = [s+c for s in res for c in character_list]
  return res
```

On your example, it gives, as expected

```
>>> comb([['P'], ['E', 'C'], ['E', 'P', 'C']])
['PEE', 'PEP', 'PEC', 'PCE', 'PCP', 'PCC']
```

A shorter version is possible using functools.reduce(), but the use of this function is not recommanded.